# Table Cell with subtitle does not trigger the segue?

Tags: ios

I have a very strange issue with the tableview:
I have a table cell where I created a segue to another tableview
I initiate the table cell using the below code with style "UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle":

The problem I have is that touch of the table cell is not triggering the segue(prepareForSegue is not called), but if I change the table cell style to default, then it works.

Does anyone know, what is wrong? Thanks a lot!

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{
    static NSString * const kPlacesCellIdentifier = @"Cell99";

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kPlacesCellIdentifier];

cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:kPlacesCellIdentifier];

//cell.editingAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
CountryCustomers *aCountryCustomer = [_countryCustomersList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = aCountryCustomer.countryName;
NSString *detailTextLable = [@"Users:" stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", aCountryCustomer.userNumbers]];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = detailTextLable;
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

//add the national flag
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",aCountryCustomer.countryName];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];



return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you are create another cell, you shouldnt call

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:kPlacesCellIdentifier];
```

after

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kPlacesCellIdentifier];
```

since `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` already creates the cell

To change the cell type go to the story board and change, select the cell, and change style to Subtitle

[image]

Comment: and then how do I change the cell style so it will show subtitles? I have changed my coding to:
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kPlacesCellIdentifier];
    
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:kPlacesCellIdentifier];}   --> but then the subtitle is gone.

Comment: @Yashu check updated answer, the screenshot will show you how